# mysql sum columns from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: tb_subjoe and tb_deliverydetails

I need to sum Price and Quantity column.  at this my code mysql When I do

```
 SELECT scode_id, scode_detail, deli_quote, SUM(deli_dequan) AS QUANTITY, SUM(deli_goodsprice) AS Good price, SUM(deli_wagesprice) AS Wage price 
FROM tb_deliverydetails 
LEFT JOIN tb_subjob 
    ON tb_subjob.scode_id = tb_deliverydetails.scode_id 
GROUP BY `deli_quote`
```

it not answer for me

[image]

Comment: First, figure out what your tables are called.

Comment: Does the image show the expected or the actual results?